# DateTime Picker em português

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker

Eu adicionei o componente de `DateTimePicker` ao meu projeto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o mesmo está todo em inglês, adicionei a option de pt-BR na function que o cria no campo, e mesmo assim ele continua em inglês. Como faço para que os meses/dias da semana fiquem pt-BR ?

```
function atualizarCalendariosHora() {
    $(".calendarioHora").mask("99/99/9999 99:99");
    $(".calendarioHora").datetimepicker("destroy");

    $(".calendarioHora:not([readonly='readonly']):not([readonly='true'])").datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
        lang: 'pt-BR',
        mask: '99/99/9999 99:99',
        onClose: function () {
            try {
                $(this).valid();
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: qual o plugin amigo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema com: `$.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');` após a definição do DateTimePicker.

```
function atualizarCalendariosHora() {
    $(".calendarioHora:not([readonly='readonly']):not([readonly='true'])").datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
        mask: '99/99/9999 99:99',
        onClose: function () {
            try {
                $(this).valid();
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    });

    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode escolher o que quer inserir de informação, por exemplo. 
DAYNAMES = Nome dos dias.
Você coloca dentro de uma array os nomes e vai aparecer em seu calendário!
O código a seguir demonstra alguns atributos que você pode alterar.

```js
$(".data").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior'
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" href="http://www.botecodigital.info/exemplos/datapicker/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.botecodigital.info/exemplos/datapicker/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.botecodigital.info/exemplos/datapicker/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="data hasDatepicker" id="dp1458823238871">
```

Você pode verificar um exemplo neste site:
http://www.botecodigital.info/exemplos/datapicker/ 
Inspecione o código fonte e verá como é simples!

Tente deixar seu script assim:

```js
function atualizarCalendariosHora() {
    $(".calendarioHora").mask("99/99/9999 99:99");
    $(".calendarioHora").datetimepicker("destroy");

    $(".calendarioHora:not([readonly='readonly']):not([readonly='true'])").datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
        lang: 'pt-BR',
       dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior',
        mask: '99/99/9999 99:99',
        onClose: function () {
            try {
                $(this).valid();
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note que o componente é o `DateTimePicker` e não o `DatePicker`.

Comment: Tenta colocar:
 locale: 'pt'

Answer (score 1):

Tente criar o DatePìcker assim:

```
$(".calendarioHora").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
});
```

Comment: Note que o componente é o `DateTimePicker` e não o `DatePicker`.